# Asymptotic exactness of Welch's t-test under arbitrary distributions

Tags: t-test, assumptions, robust

A common recommendation when using the Welch t-test for comparing two unpaired sample means is that the assumption of normality is not a problem when the sample size $n$ is bigger than some constant $c$; for example, $c=30$.

Can this recommendation be backed up using theoretic results? Specifically, is Welch's $t$-test asymptotically exact even if the distributions are not normal? Only considering well-behaved distributions, for example, finite moments.

I mostly found simulation studies investigating the robustness of Welch's $t$-test. Looking at the results, it seems like the type-I errors always converge to the nominal alpha ($.05$ in the studies I found); suggesting that Welch's $t$-test is indeed asymptotically exact. But it would be nice to know whether this is always the case.

Comment: I assume you mean even when the underlying distribution is not normal but the statistic of interest (i.e. mean) is normal right ? Because you could perform a welsh-test on the 71'st quartile and I am pretty sure it will never be exact or asymptotically normal

Comment: As far as I understand, Welch's t-test is only used to test for mean differences. Is this wrong?

Comment: There seems little to discuss. Welch's test uses the same statistic as the two-sample Student t test; it only modifies the degrees of freedom.  But since asymptotically the DF grows arbitrarily large, asymptotically the two tests are the same--and asymptotically, the Student t is exact provided the second moment of the underlying distribution is finite.

Comment: @whuber: I believe your conclusion is valid. However, isn't the premise of your argument false? The test statistics are not the same. While the nominators of the Welch and Student t test-statistic are identical, they differ in the denominator.

Comment: It depends on what version of a two-sample Student t test you're comparing it to: there is one with a "pooled" variance estimate and [another with separate variance estimates,](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda353.htm) exactly as in the Welch test.